# Allah's Mercy on His slaves

Tags: allah

There is a Sahih hadith that Allah, the Most Merciful, has 100 parts of mercy out of which He has given 1 part to the creatures and kept 99 with Him. Now 100 is not infinite. But in some places I've seen people saying that Allah, The Most Merciful, has unlimited or infinite Mercy. Confused. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to that Hadith?

Comment: Yes, here it is. In Saheeh Muslim it is narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah has one hundred parts of mercy, of which He sent down one between the jinn, mankind, the animals and the insects, by means of which they are compassionate and merciful to one another, and by means of which wild animals are kind to their offspring. And Allah has kept back ninety-nine parts of mercy with which to be merciful to His slaves of the Day of Resurrection.” (Muslim, al-Tawbah, 6908)

Comment: I don't think arithmetic really enters into this; here, the Prophet is emphasising the mercy of Allah in the hereafter, rather than in the world now.

Answer (score 2):

The hadith say: خلق الله مائة رحمة فوضع واحدة بين خلقه وخبأ عنده مائة إلا واحدة (Allah created one hundred (parts of mercy) and He distributed one amongst His creation and kept this one hundred excepting one with Himself (for the Day of Resurrection)) - Sahih Muslim (2752).

The emphasis is on the words, '**Allah created**'. Meaning, it is not referring to His Essence of Mercy. It's referring to the 'created mercy', one of which will be used up in the Dunya and the rest which will be used up in the Akhirah.

Of course, Allah's Attribute of Mercy is eternal. His Mercy will never be  (could never be) exhausted.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Jazak Allahu Khayran. That's why learning reading the original Arabic is so important. English translation can mislead. I can see its written "KhalqAllahu" (Allah created).